# which library I should use for RxAndroid and RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am trying to use RxAndroid and RxJava, but I am a bit confused which of the below mentioned library I should use??
in some tutorial they use for example the following classes which is available in

```
 compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
 compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'

.subscribe(new Subscriber<String>)
```

and some tutorial hey use for example they use the following classes which is available in the following lib

```
 compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
 compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1' 

 .subscribe(new Observer<String>)

  moreover, in this lib there is no "Unsubscribe()" method??!!
```

and in the Observer class there is something called Disposable class
which does not exist in the Subscriber class

moreover, the 
please let me know which one I should use?

**libs**:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'

compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0. You can use a Disposable and call dispose().

Answer (score 0):

In my new projects I use

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
```

Comment: but in this lib you mentioned there is no unsubscribe method..right?

Comment: You recveive disposable and you should dispose it or use CompositeDisposable for letter dispose several disposable                                               
 CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable(); compositeDisposable.add(disposable);             
compositeDisposable.clear();

Answer (score 0):

there are two mainly versions of Rxjava and RxAndroid, basically if you're using the first version (1.x.y) you should migrate to use Rxjava2.
and the reason is from the offical github repo

> Timeline plans for the 1.x line:
>
> - June 1, 2017 - feature freeze (no new operators), only bugfixes March
> - 31, 2018 - end of life, no further development

if you starting from scratch you should use version 2, as it's much more powerful than the old one and it has the Backpressure support, try to take a look on the repo and the wiki [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

Answer (score 0):

You should use RxJava2 if your starting new project, because it's faster and more optimised. There is special type for dealing with back pressure from the box. But it have more methods inside.
Disposable is just new name of Subscription class. So in RxJava1 it was Subscription.unsubscribe() now its Disposable.dispose().